# How to sort an array of objects on the basis of properties which are provided by another array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, compare, lookup

I have been working around for sorting an array of objects according to a property that doesn't exist in that array.
I had my first array like

```
const scores = [
    {
        "scoreDefinitionName": "_mo45",
        "score": 0,
        "scoreDefinitionId": {
            "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
            "idValue": "573564",
            "globalId": null,
            "version": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "scoreDefinitionName": "_sc45",
        "score": 0,
        "scoreDefinitionId": {
            "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
            "idValue": "573568",
            "globalId": null,
            "version": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "scoreDefinitionName": "_ua45",
        "score": 0,
        "scoreDefinitionId": {
            "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
            "idValue": "573572",
            "globalId": null,
            "version": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "scoreDefinitionName": "KFT",
        "score": 1,
        "scoreDefinitionId": {
            "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
            "idValue": "573576",
            "globalId": null,
            "version": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "scoreDefinitionName": "LFT",
        "score": 1,
        "scoreDefinitionId": {
            "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
            "idValue": "573580",
            "globalId": null,
            "version": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "scoreDefinitionName": "dummy",
        "score": 1,
        "scoreDefinitionId": {
            "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
            "idValue": "573584",
            "globalId": null,
            "version": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "scoreDefinitionName": "Score",
        "score": 0.32,
        "scoreDefinitionId": {
            "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
            "idValue": "573588",
            "globalId": null,
            "version": 0
        }
    }
]
```

and second array is like

```
[
  {
    variableName: "KFT",
    variable: "KFT",
    sequence: 1,
    variableDetail: {
      displayName: ""
    },
  },
  {
    variableName: "LFT",
    variable: "LFT",
    sequence: 3,
    variableDetail: {
      displayName: ""
    },
  },
  {
    variableName: "Dummy",
    variable: "dummy",
    sequence: 2,
    variableDetail: {
      displayName: ""
    }
  }
];
```

So bascially what I want to do is to sort the first array `scores` according to the sequence of that object which matches with object in second array `varibles` when the name property matches.

One work around I found is to first push the `sequence` property of `variables` array in the `scores` array and then sort according to that
But I believe it can be optimised more. Any other way to make it more optimise ?

Comment: In the `variables` array the sequence is 1, 3, 2 for KFT, LFT, Dummy. And, other elements from 'scores' array have no entries & thus no sequence. If sorting based on `sequence`, the `scores` array will show KFT, Dummy, LFT & rest of the elements have no specific sequence/sort-order. Do you need it to sort as KFT, Dummy, LFT or should it be KFT, LFT, Dummy (in which case the `sequence` is either incorrect or not applicable to the sort order).

Comment: @jsN00b need to sort it as KFT, Dummy, LFT

Comment: Already added an answer that does it as KFT, Dummy, LFT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective, with the **assumption** that the `scores` array needs to be sorted based on the `sequence` prop on the `variables` array (& not on the order in which the `variables` array is populated). In other words, the desired sort-order is KFT, Dummy, LFT, which is as per the `sequence` being 1, 2, 3; and it is not KFT, LFT, Dummy whose corresponding `sequence` is 1, 3, 2.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// method to sort using custom logic (without mutating the input array)
const mySort = (arr, ord) => (
  structuredClone(arr)                  // deep-clone to avoid mutating parameter array
  .sort(
    (
      {scoreDefinitionName: sdA},       // de-structure to access "scoreDefinitionName"
      {scoreDefinitionName: sdB}        // of both 'a' and 'b'
    ) => {
      if (sdA in ord && sdB in ord) {   // if both "scoreDefinitionName"s are in variables
        return ord[sdA] - ord[sdB]      // use the "sequence number to sort
      } else if (sdA in ord) {          // else, if only 'a' is in 'variables' array
        return -1;                      
      } else if (sdB in ord) {          // 'a' is not but 'b' is in 'variables' array
        return 1;
      } else return (                   // both 'a' and 'b' are not in the array
        sdA < sdB ? -1 : 1              // sort using the "scoreDefinitionName"
      );
    }
  )                   // implicit return of the "sort"-ed array
);

const scores = [
    {
        "scoreDefinitionName": "_mo45",
        "score": 0,
        "scoreDefinitionId": {
            "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
            "idValue": "573564",
            "globalId": null,
            "version": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "scoreDefinitionName": "_sc45",
        "score": 0,
        "scoreDefinitionId": {
            "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
            "idValue": "573568",
            "globalId": null,
            "version": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "scoreDefinitionName": "_ua45",
        "score": 0,
        "scoreDefinitionId": {
            "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
            "idValue": "573572",
            "globalId": null,
            "version": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "scoreDefinitionName": "KFT",
        "score": 1,
        "scoreDefinitionId": {
            "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
            "idValue": "573576",
            "globalId": null,
            "version": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "scoreDefinitionName": "LFT",
        "score": 1,
        "scoreDefinitionId": {
            "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
            "idValue": "573580",
            "globalId": null,
            "version": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "scoreDefinitionName": "dummy",
        "score": 1,
        "scoreDefinitionId": {
            "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
            "idValue": "573584",
            "globalId": null,
            "version": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "scoreDefinitionName": "Score",
        "score": 0.32,
        "scoreDefinitionId": {
            "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
            "idValue": "573588",
            "globalId": null,
            "version": 0
        }
    }
];

const variables = [
  {
    variableName: "KFT",
    variable: "KFT",
    sequence: 1,
    variableDetail: {
      displayName: ""
    },
  },
  {
    variableName: "LFT",
    variable: "LFT",
    sequence: 3,
    variableDetail: {
      displayName: ""
    },
  },
  {
    variableName: "Dummy",
    variable: "dummy",
    sequence: 2,
    variableDetail: {
      displayName: ""
    }
  }
];

// invoke the custom sort method
// transform 'variables' array into an object
// with key-value pair as 'variable': 'sequence'
// This helps in sorting using the sequence
console.log(
  'sorting scores arr using ordering from variables array...\n',
  mySort(
    scores,
    Object.fromEntries(
      variables.map(
        ({ variable, sequence }) => [variable, sequence]
      )
    )
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.

Comment: @jsNoob ... `sdA < sdB ? -1 : 1` ... for string based values does not guarantee an ascending alphanumeric sorting order. Also the Zero return value is missing for equal string values.

Answer (score 1):

A comparison function could be implemented in a way that it compares score-items first according to a bound map of predefined precedence entries where the `key` was retrieved from the `variable` value and and the precedence `value` was retrieved from the `sequence` value of the 2nd array's items and in a second step compares score-items by their `scoreDefinitionName`s according to an ascending sort order.

```js
function compareScoreItemsByDefinitionNameAndBoundPrecedence(a, b) {
  const precedenceLookup = this;

  const aName = a.scoreDefinitionName;
  const bName = b.scoreDefinitionName;
  const aPrecedence = precedenceLookup.get(aName) ?? null;
  const bPrecedence = precedenceLookup.get(bName) ?? null;

  return (
    (aPrecedence === null && bPrecedence !== null && 1) ||    
    (aPrecedence !== null && bPrecedence === null && -1) ||
    (aPrecedence !== null && bPrecedence !== null && aPrecedence - bPrecedence) ||
    // ascending name order if no predefined precedence
    // is available or precedence comparison value was zero.
    aName.localeCompare(bName)
  );
}

const namePrecedence = [{
  variableName: "KFT",
  variable: "KFT",
  sequence: 1,
  variableDetail: {
    displayName: ""
  },
}, {
  variableName: "LFT",
  variable: "LFT",
  sequence: 3,
  variableDetail: {
    displayName: ""
  },
}, {
  variableName: "Dummy",
  variable: "dummy",
  sequence: 2,
  variableDetail: {
    displayName: ""
  }
}];
const scores = [{
  "scoreDefinitionName": "_mo45",
  "score": 0,
  "scoreDefinitionId": {
    "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
    "idValue": "573564",
    "globalId": null,
    "version": 0
  }
}, {
  "scoreDefinitionName": "_sc45",
  "score": 0,
  "scoreDefinitionId": {
    "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
    "idValue": "573568",
    "globalId": null,
    "version": 0
  }
}, {
  "scoreDefinitionName": "_ua45",
  "score": 0,
  "scoreDefinitionId": {
    "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
    "idValue": "573572",
    "globalId": null,
    "version": 0
  }
}, {
  "scoreDefinitionName": "KFT",
  "score": 1,
  "scoreDefinitionId": {
    "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
    "idValue": "573576",
    "globalId": null,
    "version": 0
  }
}, {
  "scoreDefinitionName": "LFT",
  "score": 1,
  "scoreDefinitionId": {
    "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
    "idValue": "573580",
    "globalId": null,
    "version": 0
  }
}, {
  "scoreDefinitionName": "dummy",
  "score": 1,
  "scoreDefinitionId": {
    "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
    "idValue": "573584",
    "globalId": null,
    "version": 0
  }
}, {
  "scoreDefinitionName": "Score",
  "score": 0.32,
  "scoreDefinitionId": {
    "objectType": "ScoreDefinition",
    "idValue": "573588",
    "globalId": null,
    "version": 0
  }
}];

console.log(
  '... key value tuple of the to be created and bound precedence map ...',
  namePrecedence
    .map(({ variable, sequence }) => [variable, sequence])
);
scores.sort(
  compareScoreItemsByDefinitionNameAndBoundPrecedence
    .bind(
      new Map(
        namePrecedence
          .map(({ variable, sequence }) => [variable, sequence])
      )
    )
);
console.log({ scores });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```